# GBoard image insertion not working on pre Oreo devices with androidx

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, androidx, gboard

I followed [these](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html#kotlin) guidelines to support Keyboard image insertion into my app which is pretty straight forward:

```
val editText = object : EditText(this) {

override fun onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo: EditorInfo): InputConnection {
    val ic: InputConnection = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo)
    EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, arrayOf("image/png"))

    val callback =
            InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener { inputContentInfo, flags, opts ->
                val lacksPermission = (flags and
                        InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0
                // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1 && lacksPermission) {
                    try {
                        inputContentInfo.requestPermission()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        return@OnCommitContentListener false // return false if failed
                    }
                }

                // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously.
                // call inputContentInfo.releasePermission() as needed.

                true  // return true if succeeded
            }
    return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback)
}
}
```

But this only works on Oreo+ devices. During investigation I found out that Google's own [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-CommitContentSampleApp) stops working on pre Oreo if you migrate that app to androidx library from classic app compat library. Is there any known issue with androidx regarding this? What else I can do to support image insertion on pre Oreo devices?

Here is whats printed in logs:

```
W/ImageInsertUtil: Mime Type [image/png] is not acceptable when inserting the image
W/ImageInsertUtil: User tried to insert image in an app that does not support mimeType image/png.
W/ImageInsertUtil: Mime Type [image/gif] is not acceptable when inserting the image
W/ImageInsertUtil: User tried to insert image in an app that does not support image insertion for fallback mimetype image/gif.
W/ImageInsertUtil: Share intent [Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/png flg=0x10000001 pkg=com.xyz (has extras) }] failed to resolve in app [com.xyz]
```

GBoard falls back to sending intent to that app with action SEND if it fails to insert image. This is whats happening here.